# jetty server not responding to HTTP/2 requests

Tags: java, jetty, http2

i have implemented a http2(clear text) server in jetty, its working as expected with http1_1, but i don't know what is wrong with http/2.
is there something to do with handler?

the server is up on localhost:8080

```
//server
package server;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();

        HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        HttpConnectionFactory http11 = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig);

        HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory h2c = new HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory(httpConfig);

        ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server,http11, h2c);
        http.setPort(8080);

        // Set the connector
        server.addConnector(http);

        // set servlet handler
        ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setHandler(new RequestHandler());
        server.setHandler(context);

        server.start();
    }
}

// request handler

package server;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class RequestHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
//        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        System.out.println(baseRequest.getRequestURI());
        String method = baseRequest.getMethod();
        if(Objects.equals(method, "POST")) {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            StringBuilder requestBody = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                requestBody.append(line);
            }

            System.out.println("REQUEST BODY IS : " + requestBody.toString());
            response.setContentType("application/json");

            response.setStatus(202);
            response.getWriter().println("POST REQUEST");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("GET REQUEST ");
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.setStatus(200);
            System.out.println("Sending response");
            response.getWriter().println("{\"http-version\" : 2}");
            System.out.println("Sending response >> ");

        }
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
}
```

sending http1_1 request

[resonse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soxwy.png)

on http/2 request:
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAEmh.png)

on http/2 request the client is showing the error :

logs:

```
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
> System.IO.IOException: The request was aborted.
> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely while waiting for the next frame from the server.
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.<ReadFrameAsync>g__ThrowMissingFrame|69_1()
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ReadFrameAsync(Boolean initialFrame)
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ProcessIncomingFramesAsync()
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ThrowRequestAborted(Exception innerException)
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.CheckResponseBodyState()
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.TryEnsureHeaders()
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadResponseHeadersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
> at Pororoca.Infrastructure.Features.Requester.PororocaRequester.RequestAsync(IPororocaVariableResolver variableResolver, PororocaHttpRequest req, Boolean disableSslVerification, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\Pororoca\Pororoca\src\Pororoca.Infrastructure\Features\Requester\PororocaRequester.cs:line 51
```

Comment: What version of Jetty? and what version of Java?

Comment: Jetty version : 11.0.16
java version : 20

Comment: There is too little information to help. StackOverflow is not the right place for troubleshooting questions like this one. I suggest that you open an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues and discuss the issue there, where you would be able to provide the missing information.